# How can i increase Zend Java Bridge Log verbosity?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-server, php-java-bridge, java-bridge-method

Is possible increase log verbosity using some directives within watchdog-jb.ini ?

I can enable file logging changing the value of this directive, from 0 to 1:
-Dzend.javamw.log=0
and adding this one:
-Dzend.javamw.logfile=/usr/local/zendsvr/var/log/javamw.log

but informations logged are poor.

Mirco